# Fortran code to solve a 2D heat bar problem

Tags: debugging, error-handling, fortran, gfortran

Before I use `MPI_Type_vector`, I simply use transpose to transpose the T_l. The code can mpirun successfully. However, after I use your provided code of `MPI_Type_vector`, the code cannot mpirun successfully. Below is my code after used `MPI_Type_vector` and the error message the terminal gives me. Can you read through them and give me suggestions to fix the error? You can discard the subroutine, it is definitely correct because the only changed part is ghost swap part, if I simpliy use transpose, not error will occur.

My code:

```
program asn
    use mpi

    ! Parameter declaration
    implicit none
    integer :: ierr, processID, totalProcesses, nx, ny, i, j, r_start, r_end, numRows, iterationCount, &
    itemax, m_start, m_end, comm_count, lowProcessID, upProcessID, upSendTag, lowSendTag, dims(1), &
    request(4),rowDimensions(2),assembleDimensions(2),globalDimensions(2),startPoint(2), rowtype
    real(8) :: a, b, dx, dy, maxResidual, localMaxResidual, globalMaxResidual, pi, L
    real(8), allocatable :: x(:), y(:), U(:,:), V(:,:), U_l(:,:), V_l(:,:), T(:,:), T_l(:,:),&
    T_assemble(:,:), T_l_transpose(:,:), residual(:,:)
    logical :: periodicBoundary(1), reorderProcesses
    integer :: resized_send_type,resized_receive_type,cart_comm, L_row, typeSize, send_type, recv_type
    integer, allocatable :: rowsPerProcess(:), displacement(:)
    INTEGER(KIND=MPI_ADDRESS_KIND) :: startMemory, strideMemory

    ! MPI Initialization:
    ! Start the MPI environment, get the rank of the current process and the total number of processes.
    call MPI_INIT(ierr)
    call MPI_COMM_RANK(MPI_COMM_WORLD, processID, ierr)
    call MPI_COMM_SIZE(MPI_COMM_WORLD, totalProcesses, ierr)

    ! Solution Array Initialization:
    ! Define the dimensions of the solution array and allocate memory for it. Initialize all elements to zero.
    nx = 100
    ny = 100
    allocate(T(ny, nx))
    T = 0.0d0

    ! Physical and Numerical Parameters Initialization:
    ! Set the domain length, coefficients 'a' and 'b', and calculate grid spacings 'dx' and 'dy'.
    L = 1d0
    a = 80
    b = 0.5d0
    pi = 3.14159260
    dx = L/(nx-1)
    dy = L/(ny-1)

    ! Position Vector Initialization:
    ! Allocate memory for position vectors 'x' and 'y' and compute their values based on grid spacings.
    allocate(x(nx))
    allocate(y(ny))
    do i =1,nx
        x(i) = (i-1)*dx
        y(i) = (i-1)*dy
    end do

    ! Boundary Conditions Setup:
    ! Set the boundary values for the solution array 'T' based on a given function.
    do i = 1, nx
        T(1,i) = -cos(2 * pi * x(i) / L)**2
        T(ny,i) = -T(1,i)
    end do

    ! Velocity Field Initialization:
    ! Allocate memory for velocity fields 'U' and 'V' and compute their values based on given functions.
    allocate(U(ny,nx))
    allocate(V(ny,nx))
    do i = 1, ny
        do j = 1, nx
            U(i,j) = sin(pi * x(i) / L) * cos(pi * y(j) / L) &
                     +sin(2 * pi * x(i) / L) * cos(2 * pi * y(j) / L)
            V(i,j) = -cos(pi * x(i) / L) * sin(pi * y(j) / L) &    
                     -cos(2 * pi * x(i) / L) * sin(2 * pi * y(j) / L)
        end do
    end do 

    ! MPI Topology Creation:
    ! Create a one-dimensional Cartesian topology for processes and determine neighboring processes.
    dims(1) = totalProcesses
    periodicBoundary(1) = .false.
    reorderProcesses = .true.
    call MPI_CART_CREATE(MPI_COMM_WORLD, 1, dims, periodicBoundary, reorderProcesses, cart_comm, ierr)
    call MPI_CART_SHIFT(cart_comm, 0, 1, lowProcessID, upProcessID, ierr)

    ! Domain Decomposition:
    ! Decompose the computational domain among the available processes based on their rank.
    call DomainDecomposition(ny, totalProcesses, processID, r_start, r_end, m_start, m_end)
    
    ! Local Solution Array Initialization:
    ! Allocate memory for local solution arrays and copy the relevant sections from the global solution array.
    numRows = r_end-r_start+1
    allocate(T_l(numRows,nx))
    allocate(T_l_transpose(nx,numRows))
    T_l(:,:) = T(r_start:r_end,:)

    ! Local Velocity Field Initialization:
    ! Allocate memory for local velocity fields and copy the relevant sections from the global velocity fields.
    allocate(U_l(numRows,nx))
    allocate(V_l(numRows,nx))
    U_l(:,:) = U(r_start:r_end,:)
    V_l(:,:) = V(r_start:r_end,:)

    ! Ghost Cell Communication Initialization:
    ! Define tags for MPI communication to identify the data being sent/received.
    upSendTag = 1
    lowSendTag = 2

    ! Convergence Criteria Initialization:
    ! Allocate memory for the residual array and set the maximum allowed residual and maximum iteration count.
    allocate(residual(numRows,nx))
    iterationCount = 0
    maxResidual = 1d-5
    itemax = 20000

!                           2. calculate and update the local domain
!============================================================================================================
    ! Loop until not converged after large iteration
    do while (iterationCount < itemax)
!------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ! For red nodes
    ! The red nodes are updated based on the parity (odd or even) of 'r_start + 1'.
    ! Depending on the parity, different starting points and steps are used for the update.
    
    ! Check the parity of 'r_start + 1'
    if (mod(r_start + 1, 2) == 1) then
        ! If 'r_start + 1' is odd:
        
        ! Update the matrix for odd rows starting from the second row and third column.
        ! The updates are done in steps of 2 for both rows and columns.
        call updateMatrix(2, 3, 2, 2, T_l, U_l, V_l, a, b, dx, dy, numRows, nx)
        ! Update the matrix for even rows starting from the third row and second column.
        call updateMatrix(3, 2, 2, 2, T_l, U_l, V_l, a, b, dx, dy, numRows, nx)
    else
        ! If 'r_start + 1' is even:
        
        ! Update the matrix for even rows starting from the second row and second column.
        call updateMatrix(2, 2, 2, 2, T_l, U_l, V_l, a, b, dx, dy, numRows, nx)
        ! Update the matrix for odd rows starting from the third row and third column.
        call updateMatrix(3, 3, 2, 2, T_l, U_l, V_l, a, b, dx, dy, numRows, nx)
    end if

!------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
! Ghost row swap:
! This section of the code deals with the communication of ghost rows between adjacent processes.
! Ghost rows are boundary rows of a local domain that are used to exchange information with neighboring domains.
! Using MPI_Type_vector, we can directly send and receive rows without needing to transpose the matrix.

! Define a new MPI data type for a row of the matrix:
call MPI_Type_vector(1, nx, nx, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, rowtype, ierr)
call MPI_Type_commit(rowtype, ierr)

! Initialize communication count:
comm_count = 0

! Receive ghost row from the lower local domain (if not the first process):
if (processID > 0) then
    call MPI_IRECV(T_l(1,:), 1, rowtype, lowProcessID, upSendTag, &
                   cart_comm, request(comm_count+1), ierr)
    comm_count = comm_count + 1
end if

! Send ghost row to the upper local domain (if not the last process):
if (processID < totalProcesses-1) then
    call MPI_ISEND(T_l(numRows-1,:), 1, rowtype, upProcessID, upSendTag, &
                   cart_comm, request(comm_count+1), ierr)
    comm_count = comm_count + 1
end if

! Receive ghost row from the upper local domain (if not the last process):
if (processID < totalProcesses-1) then
    call MPI_IRECV(T_l(numRows,:), 1, rowtype, upProcessID, lowSendTag, &
                   cart_comm, request(comm_count+1), ierr)
    comm_count = comm_count + 1
end if

! Send ghost row to the lower local domain (if not the first process):
if (processID > 0) then
    call MPI_ISEND(T_l(2,:), 1, rowtype, lowProcessID, lowSendTag, &
                   cart_comm, request(comm_count+1), ierr)
    comm_count = comm_count + 1
end if

! Wait for all non-blocking communication operations to complete:
if (comm_count > 0) then
    call MPI_WAITALL(comm_count, request, MPI_STATUSES_IGNORE, ierr)
end if

! Free the custom MPI data type:
call MPI_Type_free(rowtype, ierr)


!-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ! For black nodes
    ! The black nodes are updated similarly to the red nodes but with different starting points.
    ! The parity of 'r_start + 1' determines the starting points for the update.

    ! Check the parity of 'r_start + 1'
    if (mod(r_start + 1, 2) == 1) then
        ! If 'r_start + 1' is odd:
        
        ! Update the matrix for even rows starting from the second row and second column.
        call updateMatrix(2, 2, 2, 2, T_l, U_l, V_l, a, b, dx, dy, numRows, nx)
        ! Update the matrix for odd rows starting from the third row and third column.
        call updateMatrix(3, 3, 2, 2, T_l, U_l, V_l, a, b, dx, dy, numRows, nx)
    else
        ! If 'r_start + 1' is even:
        
        ! Update the matrix for odd rows starting from the second row and third column.
        call updateMatrix(2, 3, 2, 2, T_l, U_l, V_l, a, b, dx, dy, numRows, nx)
        ! Update the matrix for even rows starting from the third row and second column.
        call updateMatrix(3, 2, 2, 2, T_l, U_l, V_l, a, b, dx, dy, numRows, nx)
    end if

!-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
! Ghost row swap:
! This section of the code deals with the communication of ghost rows between adjacent processes.
! Ghost rows are boundary rows of a local domain that are used to exchange information with neighboring domains.
! Using MPI_Type_vector, we can directly send and receive rows without needing to transpose the matrix.

! Define a new MPI data type for a row of the matrix:
call MPI_Type_vector(1, nx, nx, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, rowtype, ierr)
call MPI_Type_commit(rowtype, ierr)

! Initialize communication count:
comm_count = 0

! Receive ghost row from the lower local domain (if not the first process):
if (processID > 0) then
    call MPI_IRECV(T_l(1,:), 1, rowtype, lowProcessID, upSendTag, &
                   cart_comm, request(comm_count+1), ierr)
    comm_count = comm_count + 1
end if

! Send ghost row to the upper local domain (if not the last process):
if (processID < totalProcesses-1) then
    call MPI_ISEND(T_l(numRows-1,:), 1, rowtype, upProcessID, upSendTag, &
                   cart_comm, request(comm_count+1), ierr)
    comm_count = comm_count + 1
end if

! Receive ghost row from the upper local domain (if not the last process):
if (processID < totalProcesses-1) then
    call MPI_IRECV(T_l(numRows,:), 1, rowtype, upProcessID, lowSendTag, &
                   cart_comm, request(comm_count+1), ierr)
    comm_count = comm_count + 1
end if

! Send ghost row to the lower local domain (if not the first process):
if (processID > 0) then
    call MPI_ISEND(T_l(2,:), 1, rowtype, lowProcessID, lowSendTag, &
                   cart_comm, request(comm_count+1), ierr)
    comm_count = comm_count + 1
end if

! Wait for all non-blocking communication operations to complete:
if (comm_count > 0) then
    call MPI_WAITALL(comm_count, request, MPI_STATUSES_IGNORE, ierr)
end if

! Free the custom MPI data type:
call MPI_Type_free(rowtype, ierr)


!------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
! update and check stopping criteria

        ! update iteration notation
        iterationCount = iterationCount+1
        ! calculate the maximum residual on the global domain 
        ! this calculate residual on each local node
        do i = 2, numRows-1
            do j = 2, ny-1
            ! residual = B-Ax, where B is RHS of equation, Ax is LHS of equation
                residual(i,j) = 0 - a * U_l(i,j) * ((T_l(i+1,j) - T_l(i-1,j)) / (2 * dx)) &
                              - a * V_l(i,j) * ((T_l(i,j+1) - T_l(i,j-1)) / (2* dy)) &
                              + ((T_l(i+1,j) - 2 * T_l(i,j) + T_l(i-1,j)) / dx**2) &
                              + ((T_l(i,j+1) - 2 * T_l(i,j) + T_l(i,j-1)) / dy**2) &
                              + b * T_l(i,j)
            end do
        end do
        
        localMaxResidual = maxval(abs(residual)) ! calculate the maximum residual over the local domain
        call MPI_ALLREDUCE(localMaxResidual, globalMaxResidual, 1, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION,&
         MPI_MAX, cart_comm, ierr) !calculate the maximum residual over all domain

        ! check if the maximum residual is smaller than setted
        if (globalMaxResidual < maxResidual) then
            exit
        end if
!------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    end do
```

My error:

```
 Program received signal SIGABRT: Process abort signal.

Backtrace for this error:

Could not print backtrace: executable file is not an executable

Primary job  terminated normally, but 1 process returned
a non-zero exit code. Per user-direction, the job has been aborted.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
mpirun noticed that process rank 1 with PID 0 on node Daniels-Air exited on signal 6 (Abort trap: 6).
```

Before I use `MPI_Type_vector`, I simply use transpose to transpose the T_l. The code can mpirun successfully. However, after I use your provided code of `MPI_Type_vector`, the code cannot mpirun successfully. Below is my code after used `MPI_Type_vector` and the error message the terminal gives me. Can you read through them and give me suggestions to fix the error? You can discard the subroutine, it is definitely correct because the only changed part is ghost swap part, if I simpliy use transpose, not error will occur.

Comment: Welcome, I suggest taking the [tour]. How *exactly* are you compiling and running the code? In which operating system? Which compiler?

Comment: In macos. However, in linux, I also cannot run it. The compiler is BBEdit.

Could I have your email? I could send the overal code to you.

Comment: I really strongly  suggest to take the tour I linked in my previous comment. Also see  [ask]. Do not send any materials by e-mail. Instead put all that is necessary into the question [mre].

Comment: Note that BBEdit is not a compiler, only a text editor. You have to show us what *exactly* you are doing. Which exact commands you are running.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).